# Appcompat toolbar list item background color

Tags: android, toolbar, android-styles, android-menu

I can successful change the background color of the popupmenu to white as per the requirement but the list item does not follow. I'm using this code:

```
<style name="ToolbarTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorToolbar</item> <!-- green -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and passing it directly to Toolbar using `app:theme`.

Unfortunately, this is what's happening:

[image]

How can I make the list item white and the text color as black?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app:popupTheme` to change color of the list items.

Toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ToolbarOverlay"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Themes:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ToolbarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Result:

[Green toolbar with list with white background and black text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOhy9.png)